# Server Side Rendering with Angular and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, server-side-rendering

I was using the server side rendering concept in Angular for UI and Server is on Node.js. So what I was doing is rendering the HTML Part when I hit API from Angular Component and that rendered part is shown on the Screen.

Now the Problem is their are some anchor TAGS with href

example- `href='/dashboard/cop/batting'`  HTML rendered from API.

Now when I click this link my whole angular application RESTARTS and from app.module.ts then sets routing.

This takes and lots of time and disturb my APP flow.

I have also tried `href='/#/dashboard/cop/batting'` which i was get from this [Article](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/navigation/)

What i want is to RESTART the whole application just Stay on that respective component and do the WORK.

Comment: Have you thought about using [routerLink](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links) rather than `href`? I am assuming you're using routing in your app.

Comment: @R.Richards, Yes i know but I was setting  the plain html to the component <div> THE RENDERED PART </div> .The Router link can not be use because i have not included ANGULAR in Rendered PART. I have try this.

Answer (score -1):

using href created this issue it will reload the page you should use [routerLink] directive for route change

Comment: Yes i know but I was setting the plain html to the component                   `<div> THE RENDERED PART </div>` .The Router link can not be use because i have not included ANGULAR in Rendered PART. I have try this.

Comment: I think you can use  <div><ng-template #container></ng-template></div> than. May be it works.